# How to pass an argument in a react custom hook in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props, react-custom-hooks

I am trying to pass a string value in a custom hook call to the hook file itself. For example, I have a json file I want to pass to a custom hook to get that data, however in my current implementation, I am getting an error of `TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ string: any; }'.` even when I specify the prop types. Why is this happening?

1. Custom hook to dynamically call a JSON file for its data

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

interface APICallProps {
    apiCall: string
}

const useFetchSecurityData = ({ string: apiCall }) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true)
    const [data, setData] = useState<null>(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    const fetchData = async () => {
        axios.get(apiCall)
            .then(res => {
                setData(res.data)
            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err))
        setLoading(false)
    }

    return { data, loading }
}

export default useFetchSecurityData
```

2. Implementation of custom hook on a page layout

```
const ChartArea = () => {
  const [incidents, setIncidents] = useState([])
  const { data, loading } = useFetchSecurityData('incidents.json')
  // const { data, loading } = useFetchIncidents()

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [loading, data])

  const fetchData = () => {
    try {
      let rawData = (data) ?? []
      setIncidents(rawData)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`{ string: apiCall }` is not the correct syntax for typing in this scenario.

`{ string: apiCall }` is asking to destructure your `props` for the component, and in props their should be a property called `string` which you wish to alias as `apiCall`.

Typing for a hook should look like one of the following:

```
interface MyReturnType {
    data: any;
    loading: boolean;
}

interface MyCustomHookFn {
    (propA: string, propB: number, propC: Date) => MyReturnType
}

const useMyCustomHook: MyCustomHookFn = (propA, propB, propC) => {
    ...
}
```

OR

```
const useMyCustomHook = (propA: string, propB: number, propC: Date) => {
    ...
}
```

---

Previous examples for components retained just in case someone wants them.

Typing for a component should look something like:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';

interface ExampleComponentProps {
    apiCall: string
}

const ExampleComponent: FC<APICallProps> = ({ apiCall }) => {
    ...
}
```

OR

```
import React from 'react';

interface ExampleComponentProps {
    apiCall: string
}

const ExampleComponent = ({ apiCall }: APICallProps) => {
    ...
}
```